# What is the difference between 'configuredLevel' and 'effectiveLevel' in /actuator/logger response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring boot actuator library and can't seem to figure out the exact difference between the response returned when I hit the resource URI /actuator/loggers/{logger_id}.

The returned response is usally like,

```
{
    "configuredLevel": null,
    "effectiveLevel": INFO
}
```

What do configuredLevel and effectiveLevel indicate here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `configuredLevel` is the explicitly configured logging level for that logger and is `null` if not explicitly configured. If the `configuredLevel` is not `null`, the `effectiveLevel` is equal to the `configuredLevel`. If the `configuredLevel` is `null`, the `effectiveLevel` is equal to the logging level of the logger's parent.